# Write to an Excel cell from VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to write to an Excel cell in VB.NET Using the following code:

```
Dim RowCntr As Integer = 2
Dim ColCntr As Integer = 1

CellStart = xlWorkSheet.Cells(RowCntr, ColCntr).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
xlWorkSheet.Range(CellStart).Value = Reader.GetValue(0).ToString
ColCntr += ColCntr + 2
```

I get the following error:

> System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'Address' on type
> 'Range' not found.'

The Excel file is open and has a header information and the first row has column names all written to it by my program.

Comment: When you write the code like this, you'll have to set the "Embed Interop Types" property of the Excel reference to False.  Alternatively, use an extra variable of type Range to store the cell.  And you surely meant ColCntr += 2

Comment: Use a lib like EPPlus, OpenXml, ClosedXml etc to create Excel files, not interop